# Allowing Django admin.site.register to Take more than 3 arguments

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to use both an image cropping tool and Django sortable tool on the same model. However, it says I can only add up to 3 positional arguments. What does this mean exactly, is there a particular solution for this or a work around?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Rower, Race, Leadership, Event
from image_cropping import ImageCroppingMixin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin

class MyModelAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class MyModelAdminSorting(SortableAdminMixin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Rower, MyModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Race)
admin.site.register(Leadership, MyModelAdminSorting, MyModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Event)
```

Error: admin.site.register(Leadership, MyModelAdminSorting, MyModelAdmin)
TypeError: register() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you do it.

You create a single custom `LeadershipAdmin` where you inherit from where you want, something like:

```py
class LeadershipAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, SortableAdminMixin):
    pass
```

Since the above code will take care of inheriting both the cropping mixin and Django's `ModelAdmin`.

Then you only register the `LeadershipAdmin`:

```py
admin.site.register(Leadership, LeadershipAdmin)
```

There's only **one** admin class registered per model, not a list of them.

Comment: when I try this the ImageCroppingMixin becomes obsolete and stops functioning as it should.

Comment: Maybe you don't wanna use the `Mixin` by default but rather use the `ImageWidget` provided by `image_cropping` and override the form from your Model Admin. My answer explains only how registration of model admins works, not underlying issues with a 3rd party package.